# Simplicial spaces and reflexive coequalisers

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories, cofibrations

Let $X_\bullet$ be a simplicial space. Consider the reflexive coequaliser of $X_1\rightrightarrows X_0$, which we call $X$. Then we clearly have a map $\varphi\colon |X_\bullet|\to X$, where $|X_\bullet|=\int^{n\in \Delta}X_n\times \Delta^n$ is the geometric realisation.

Can one give a useful criterion which ensures that $\varphi$ is a (weak) equivalence? (If possible, one which does not involve an ‘extra degeneracy’ $s_{-1}\colon X_n\to X_{n+1}$) I am willing to assume that $X_\bullet$ is proper, so $|X_\bullet|$ should calculate the homotopy colimit of $X_\bullet$, whereas $X$ is the strict colimit. However, we clearly need more than that. Can we formulate a condition for (some of) the face and degeneracy maps?

Comment: If $X_\bullet$ is a simplicial _set_, then you are describing the map from the geometric realization to its sets of path-components. So for simplicial sets the map is an equivalence iff the geometric realization is homotopy-discrete.

Comment: True, in this case, that’s the full story! But otherwise?

Comment: There is a general statement in Dugger's [A primer on homotopy colimits](http://math.uoregon.edu/~ddugger/hocolim.pdf) giving a nice criterion for a homotopy colimit to be weakly equivalent to the colimit in terms of the fiber category of a simplicial space (Theorem 22.2). Might that be helpful?

Comment: The standard condition would be that $X_\bullet$ should be projectively cofibrant.